# Excluding results in MySQL on JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, birt

Below is my MySQL statement:

```
select
    tableT.id,
    tableTGroupName,
    tableTGroupSortOrder,
    tableT_group.Deleted as tableTGroupDeleted,
    tableTSuiteName,
    tableTSuiteSortOrder,
    tableT_suite.Deleted as tableTSuiteDeleted,
    tableTCaseName, 
    tableTCaseSortOrder,
    tableT_case.Deleted as tableTCaseDeleted,
    DbPackageName,
    E_imgLR as Eimg, 
    R_imgLR as Rimg,
    tableTResultState,
    tableTResultComment
from 
    tableT_result
    inner join tableT on tableT_id = tableT.id
    inner join tableT_run on tableT_run_id = tableT_run.id
    inner join db_package on db_package_id = db_package.id
    inner join tableT_case on tableT_case_id = tableT_case.id
    inner join tableT_suite on tableT_suite_id = tableT_suite.id
    inner join tableT_group on tableT_group_id = tableT_group.id
    left outer join E_img_lo_r on tableT_case.e_img_id = E_img_lo_r.e_img_id or tableT_suite.e_img_id = E_img_lo_r.e_img_id -- Problematic line
    left outer join result_image_low_res on tableT_result.result_image_id = result_image_low_res.result_image_id
where
    db_package_label_id = ?
order by 
    tableTGroupSortOrder, 
    tableTSuiteSortOrder, 
    tableTCaseSortOrder
```

In the end this statement gives me 16 rows, 3 rows(results) are redundant. 3 x 2 rows have the same ids like : (234,234) (71,71) (445,445). Line

```
left outer join E_img_lo_r on tableT_case.e_img_id = E_img_lo_r.e_img_id or tableT_suite.e_img_id = E_img_lo_r.e_img_id
```

Causes this, I can use DISTINCT to eliminate duplicate IDs but the content of the rows are not the same. This is why I don't want to eliminate the necessary row.

My purpose is first to check if "tableT_case" has the image, if yes use it, if not use the one from "tableT_suite", if "tableT_suite" also doesn't have the image then take the default "No image". Afaik if-else is not possible on join statements. When both tables contain an image then it takes both which I don't want. I need this for a Birt report, we don't want to display wrong images on the report. I would be glad for any tips.

Comment: I just can't face working with that naming policy

Comment: Not sure I follow everything, but you might want to look into [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: @Strawberry I had to play with the table names a little bit to consume privacy... I know they look silly...

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add an `and`? Change the problematic line to:

```
left outer join E_img_lo_r
on
tableT_case.e_img_id = E_img_lo_r.e_img_id
or 
(
    tableT_case.e_img_id != E_img_lo_r.e_img_id
    and
    tableT_suite.e_img_id = E_img_lo_r.e_img_id
)
```

Comment: I need the images from "tableT_case", this is why I cant make !=

Comment: That's what this does... it gives you the records from E_img_lo_r matching the ID in T_Case and, ONLY if there aren't any matching records for the ID in T_Case, it gives you the records matching the ID from T_Suite instead.

Isn't that exactly what you requested when you said "My purpose is first to check if "tableT_case" has the image, if yes use it, if not use the one from "tableT_suite", if "tableT_suite" also doesn't have the image then take the default "No image"."???

Comment: Sorry I just read the part after "or" as your answer, but your statement gives exactly the same result as the problematic line, returns 16 rows, it is basicly the same thing.